# How to perform array_intersection in spark 2.4

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to perform array intersection in spark 2.4 using higher order functions. However, I am facing some issue. Here is the code

```
val my_array = Array("1","2")
spark.sql(s"""select array_intersect( array("1"), $my_array ) as intersection""").show

org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
extraneous input '[' expecting {'(', 'SELECT', 'FROM', 'ADD', 'AS', 'ALL', 'ANY', 'DISTINCT', 'WHERE', 'GROUP', 'BY', 'GROUPING', 'SETS', 'CUBE', 'ROLLUP', 'ORDER', 'HAVING', 'LIMIT', 'AT', 'OR', 'AND', 'IN', NOT, 'NO', 'EXISTS', 'BETWEEN', 'LIKE', RLIKE, 'IS', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 'NULLS', 'ASC', 'DESC', 'FOR', 'INTERVAL', 'CASE', 'WHEN', 'THEN', 'ELSE', 'END', 'JOIN', 'CROSS', 'OUTER', 'INNER', 'LEFT', 'SEMI', 'RIGHT', 'FULL', 'NATURAL', 'ON', 'PIVOT', 'LATERAL', 'WINDOW', 'OVER', 'PARTITION', 'RANGE', 'ROWS', 'UNBOUNDED', 'PRECEDING', 'FOLLOWING', 'CURRENT', 'FIRST', 'AFTER', 'LAST', 'ROW', 'WITH', 'VALUES', 'CREATE', 'TABLE', 'DIRECTORY', 'VIEW', 'REPLACE', 'INSERT', 'DELETE', 'INTO', 'DESCRIBE', 'EXPLAIN', 'FORMAT', 'LOGICAL', 'CODEGEN', 'COST', 'CAST', 'SHOW', 'TABLES', 'COLUMNS', 'COLUMN', 'USE', 'PARTITIONS', 'FUNCTIONS', 'DROP', 'UNION', 'EXCEPT', 'MINUS', 'INTERSECT', 'TO', 'TABLESAMPLE', 'STRATIFY', 'ALTER', 'RENAME', 'ARRAY', 'MAP', 'STRUCT', 'COMMENT', 'SET', 'RESET', 'DATA', 'START', 'TRANSACTION', 'COMMIT', 'ROLLBACK', 'MACRO', 'IGNORE', 'BOTH', 'LEADING', 'TRAILING', 'IF', 'POSITION', 'EXTRACT', '+', '-', '*', 'DIV', '~', 'PERCENT', 'BUCKET', 'OUT', 'OF', 'SORT', 'CLUSTER', 'DISTRIBUTE', 'OVERWRITE', 'TRANSFORM', 'REDUCE', 'SERDE', 'SERDEPROPERTIES', 'RECORDREADER', 'RECORDWRITER', 'DELIMITED', 'FIELDS', 'TERMINATED', 'COLLECTION', 'ITEMS', 'KEYS', 'ESCAPED', 'LINES', 'SEPARATED', 'FUNCTION', 'EXTENDED', 'REFRESH', 'CLEAR', 'CACHE', 'UNCACHE', 'LAZY', 'FORMATTED', 'GLOBAL', TEMPORARY, 'OPTIONS', 'UNSET', 'TBLPROPERTIES', 'DBPROPERTIES', 'BUCKETS', 'SKEWED', 'STORED', 'DIRECTORIES', 'LOCATION', 'EXCHANGE', 'ARCHIVE', 'UNARCHIVE', 'FILEFORMAT', 'TOUCH', 'COMPACT', 'CONCATENATE', 'CHANGE', 'CASCADE', 'RESTRICT', 'CLUSTERED', 'SORTED', 'PURGE', 'INPUTFORMAT', 'OUTPUTFORMAT', DATABASE, DATABASES, 'DFS', 'TRUNCATE', 'ANALYZE', 'COMPUTE', 'LIST', 'STATISTICS', 'PARTITIONED', 'EXTERNAL', 'DEFINED', 'REVOKE', 'GRANT', 'LOCK', 'UNLOCK', 'MSCK', 'REPAIR', 'RECOVER', 'EXPORT', 'IMPORT', 'LOAD', 'ROLE', 'ROLES', 'COMPACTIONS', 'PRINCIPALS', 'TRANSACTIONS', 'INDEX', 'INDEXES', 'LOCKS', 'OPTION', 'ANTI', 'LOCAL', 'INPATH', STRING, BIGINT_LITERAL, SMALLINT_LITERAL, TINYINT_LITERAL, INTEGER_VALUE, DECIMAL_VALUE, DOUBLE_LITERAL, BIGDECIMAL_LITERAL, IDENTIFIER, BACKQUOTED_IDENTIFIER}(line 1, pos 36)

== SQL ==
select array_intersect( array("1"), [Ljava.lang.String;@f24a38a ) as intersection
------------------------------------^^^
```

When I try to hard code it works fine -

```
scala> spark.sql(s"""select array_intersect( array("1"), array("1","2") ) as intersection""").show
+------------+                                                                  
|intersection|
+------------+
|         [1]|
+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your `$my_array` into the appropriate string representation first, e.g. (cf [mkString](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Array.html#mkString(start:String,sep:String,end:String):String)):

```
val my_array_str = my_array.mkString("Array(\"", "\", \"", "\")")
```

then you can use

```
spark.sql(s"""select array_intersect( array("1"), $my_array_str ) as intersection""").show
```

To understand the difference, compare

```
scala> s"$my_array"
res5: String = [Ljava.lang.String;@128acee
```

with

```
scala> s"$my_array_str"
res6: String = Array("1", "2")
```

Comment: can u explain what `Array(\"", "\", \"", "\")` does?

Comment: mkString starts the string representation with Array(" then all elements are added separated with "," and finally mkString adds a ") at the end. So it converts the java array object to the string representation you need.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by defining as **string** then casting to **array (my_array)** in sql statement.

***`Example`***

```
val my_array ="""1,2"""
spark.sql(s"""select array_intersect(array(1),array(${my_array}))""").show()
//+--------------------------------------+
//|array_intersect(array(1), array(1, 2))|
//+--------------------------------------+
//|                                   [1]|
#+--------------------------------------+
```

Comment: thanks for this. If i have 10M records, then will this be an optimized solution? because the sql statement is creating an array based on the string input for every record?